# How can I read a cookie set in PHP with jquery in another HTML page

Tags: php, jquery, html

PHP code on login.php

```
If (isset($_post['submit]))
{
  username = trim($post['username]);
  $sql = "select password from user where username = 'username'  ";
  $result = mysqli_query($connect,$sql) or die();
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  If ($row['password'] == md5($password))
  {
    setcookie('username', $row['username'], '/');
    Header('location:index.html');
  };
```

Jquery code on index.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  Var username = $.cookie('username');
  If(username == undefined) {
  Window.location.href="login.html";
} else {
  Alert('welcome'+user+'to my site');
});
```

Comment: check in your browser if the `username` cookie is set or not after you log in.  Note that md5 is not safe for passwords as it's fast , use the php [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) instead

Comment: That clip of code couldn't possibly work, due to **various** reasons. Also unclear what exactly you are really asking for.

Comment: `md5($password)` AAAAAAAAHHHHHH! [**DO NOT USE MD5 FOR PASSWORD HASHING!**](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52461/how-weak-is-md5-as-a-password-hashing-function) Use `password_hash()`.

Comment: Thank you all for hose remarks and for making me notice the md5 insecurity.but how can I check that the cookie is set or not?

Answer (score 3):

First line of PHP should be:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
```

You forgot the ' after submit. Second line:

```
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
```

You forgot $ before username and '. Third line:

```
$sql = "SELECT password FROM user WHERE username = '$username'";
```

Your SQL query would have given wrong info.

My guess is that the JQuery should work, but the PHP code is not setting the cookie. Additionally, use password_hash() to protect users passwords.

Comment: How can I check  that phpnas set the cookie and if not how can I properly do it please

Comment: You can use your brower to see if the cookie is being set properly. Here's how to do that https://kb.iu.edu/d/ajfi

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that check on the client side?

But if you must:
check if the cookie is actually set and sent. Developer Tools give you details on that.

If so, please check if the cookie is created with the HttpOnly Flag. In case it is, you will have no access to the cookie from the client side for security reasons.

Comment: Please can u tell me more about the HttpOnly Flag!?

Comment: It's ok I read about the HttpOnly Flag I'm sure this is the reason why I can't read the cookie on the client side

Comment: Is there another way to check that the user is logged from the client side after the server side has confirmed it?

Comment: @besama Well you could just "ask" the server. By sending an ajax get request. The server then checks and returns JSON encoded result you can work with (i.e. teh logged in users data).

Comment: Thanks @Stefan Dochow can I have an example please?

Comment: @besama How to make such a request is explained here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the time for cookie then it's working fine. Here is the working example:

```
<?php
setcookie('username', 'Test', time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
?>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(function(){
            $('document').ready(function(){
        alert($.cookie("username"));
            });
        });

</script>
```